# USB powered speakers working on PC but not on adapter

Tags: usb, audio, power-supply, bluetooth, speakers

I've bought Elegiant SR300 speakers. Recommend power supply is 5v 2A USB adapter to avoid ground loop noise. It's working on all USB ports of my PC. However, I couldn't get them running on any USB adapter / charger, tried 5v 2.4A (non fast charger) and some fast chargers. What happens with adapters, is only left speaker gives very very low noisy sound. At least 4 adapters / chargers tried. Same result for all. Is there any difference between PC USB ports and Charger Adapter ports in terms of power delivery configuration? Anything I'm missing?

**Edit:**

*After some troubleshooting and testing various adapters, their current and trying another speaker, I rephrase my question as follows:*

I've bought Bluetooth speakers having 3.5mm jack. Recommend power supply is USB. Works with jack only if both Jack and USB connected to PC. If USB is connected to adapter (tried many), one of the stereo channel is replaced by noise. However Bluetooth input works fine in this case. Can you spot the issue?

Comment: For the intended purpose here (power) there isn't much difference. Your title is a bit misleading because Elegiant SR300 speakers AREN'T "USB speakers", they're USB powered active speakers. The difference being the former includes an external (generic) USB audio device and the latter are amplified/active regular speakers that incidentally are designed to be powered from a PC USB port or (5V) external power supply. In the former both power and audio signal are carried by the USB connection while in the latter uses the standard (3.5mm) audio output from the sound source.

Comment: You should contact tech support. The problem is unrelated to the PC.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I've updated title if it was confusing. Since it's working fine with PC, it's not defect of speakers I think. Just little ground loop noise, but with adapters, output is all like nothing.

Comment: it is *plausible* that the chargers you are attempting to use are downgrading current. There exist designs that negotiate available power and if the speakers are not responding to this negotiation, then the charger may be defaulting to e.g. "trickle charge" mode which would not be sufficient for amplification. The simplest definition (without caveats like real power etc) "is watts = amps times volts," and if the amperage is choked down, you cannot get 10 watts the speakers claim. at 500mA, the max possible would be about 2.5 watts

Comment: @Yorik I've attempted many tests today. Found that there was no issue with adapters. Tested another speaker with them and also measured amperage. I've updated my question, please check.

Comment: and the reason I don't want to plug both USB power and 3.5mm jack in the PC is; minor ground loop noise (though not very noticeable).

Comment: Have you tried using the charger as power source, but using your phone or some other device (not the PC) for Audio ?

Comment: I'll update trying now.

Comment: Oh same issue when plugged 3.5mm on phone. Some voices, tones (a whole channel?) vanished.

Comment: Could this be a device grounding problem?

Comment: I suspected that and Grounded my PC case, it removed current from the Case but strangely noise from speakers increase significantly. When removed grounding wire, noise back to original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. Sorry to bother you all. I'm not a professional for electronics or electrical items but have limited experience in repairing such items. After opening primary speaker box and investigating wiring on its electronic board, I found that the wire connector having 5 pins (USB +, USB -, Aux +, Aux -, Aux G) had loose/pulled out Aux Ground pin. Moreover, there was an Aux out connector on the board that disturbed sound when touched. I suspected its metal base was touching other lanes on board and I fixed it by raising a bit. And thankfully, problem resolved! Perhaps one of these or both were the reasons that Aux was missing sound and giving noises specially on separate adapter. However Bluetooth was giving clear sound.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a set of speakers which has a similar problem, and your response was the only directly applicable one after a lot of hunting.  Short answer for anyone following: this is an internal electronics issue.

My speakers aren't expensive but they worked well until quitting without apparent reason a day ago - the [Creative Pebble Plus](https://www.pcmag.com/reviews/creative-pebble-plus). They are powered by USB, and accept audio input from a standard headphone jack.  They worked great at first, but when the USB power was plugged in to my PC they would "pop" approximately once every second which seemed to be a grounding issue, so I connected the USB to a power adapter and all was well until 2 days ago.

When I booted up this time the power light stayed off, so I did the usual thing: start at the wall and work through the system.  I verified that the power bar was providing power (even unplugged and reseated it), then that my USB power adapter worked (tested with other devices, also swapped in 2 different ones), then tested that the USB power cord from the speaker itself worked.

This was the mystery: the speakers would power-up when the USB power cord was plugged in to my PC, but they would not power up at all when plugged in to a power adapter.  After much internet hunting I'm convinced @Ghazi has found the source: an internal electronic issue, probably related in my case to cheap manufacturing and/or planned obsolescence.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm glad my question helped you and thanks for recognizing my answer. I expect you to thumbs up my question/answer.